# Override inline css?

Tags: html, css

I have css in my html code such as this:

```
 <img src="" style="width:500px;">
```

I want the image to be large on normal desktop/laptop screens.

But I want the image to be responsive on mobile.

I've got img in my css file set to width:100% at a certain screen resolution but my inline css code above seems to override my css in the styles file.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.container .row p img {
    width:100%;
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can only override an inline style in CSS with an `!important` rule, otherwise you need JavaScript to change the style on the element. Read about specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I tried to answer, but it wouldn't let me. Using the !important tag will let the browser know that one is to be used.

This should work

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.container .row p img {
    width:100% !important;
}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `!important`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.container .row p img {
    width:100% !important;
}
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought too but I didn't know if it was the right solution.  Apparently, it is!

Comment: Not a good practice to use !important. Also, if you are using inline CSS and !important, its good time to review, restructure your code to avoid inline CSS and !important. Refer https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

Using the !important tag will let the browser know that one is to be used.

This should work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.container .row p img {
    width:100% !important;
}
}
```